# Sqlite database not connect Xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello developers I am newby Xamarin.Forms And I want To connect SQlite with Xamarin.Forms. But Does not connect. I copied it Microsoft's oficial documentations about SQlite. This is my code

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
"database.db3");
    var con = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
}
```

when I click button gives this Error

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.'

where is my Error I can not Find that. Thanks for attention.

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915404/the-type-initializer-for-sqlite-sqliteconnection-threw-an-exception)

Comment: Probably missing a reference to a NuGet package.

Comment: I hope you are using https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.7.302-beta

Comment: yes  I Am using 1.7.302-Beta